# security error the operation is insecure in firefox document.stylesheets

Tags: javascript, security, error-handling, stylesheet

The following code throws an error in the Firefox Console at the line with the continue.

```
SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
if( !sheet.cssRules ) { continue; }
```

However does not in Chrome and IE 11... Can someone explain the -why- of this? (And also how to re-work to make it safe.) I assume this is a cross-domain issue, but I'm stuck as how to re-work the code properly.

```
var bgColor = getStyleRuleValue('background-color', 'bg_selector');

function getStyleRuleValue(style, selector, sheet) {
  var sheets = typeof sheet !== 'undefined' ? [sheet] : document.styleSheets;
  for (var i = 0, l = sheets.length; i < l; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    if( !sheet.cssRules ) { continue; }
    for (var j = 0, k = sheet.cssRules.length; j < k; j++) {
      var rule = sheet.cssRules[j];
      if (rule.selectorText && rule.selectorText.split(',').indexOf(selector) !== -1) 
         return rule.style[style];            
     }
   }
  return null;
 }
```

Comment: [X] SecurityError: The operation is insecure. 

if( !sheet.cssRules ) { continue; }

Comment: How is that insecure? Are you passing in a CrossSite stylesheet? Smells Buggy, I'd file with Firefox.

Comment: It's a Wordpress site so, yes, some of the stylesheets are going to be from other domains---like Google for example. I'm obviously not advanced enough to understand why this is an issue in the above code.

Comment: I think maybe FF doesn't like the fact the sheet comes from elsewhere and you are evaluating it with javascript. Imagine, `if( !sheet.cssRules ){do bad stuff with the contents of sheet...} If you remove the negation and only execute the block if true does that help? Or, maybe remove the check and make sure you only have css rules in those files.

Comment: This is an old question, but adding a new style element https://stackoverflow.com/a/29833756/4621141 worked for me in bypassing this Firefox restriction

Answer (score 22):

To circumvent the SecurityError in Firefox when attempting to access the cssRules attribute, you must use a `try/catch` statement. The following should work:

```
// Example call to process_stylesheet() with StyleSheet object.
process_stylesheet(window.document.styleSheets[0]);

function process_stylesheet(ss) {
  // cssRules respects same-origin policy, as per
  // https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=49001#c10.
  try {
    // In Chrome, if stylesheet originates from a different domain,
    // ss.cssRules simply won't exist. I believe the same is true for IE, but
    // I haven't tested it.
    //
    // In Firefox, if stylesheet originates from a different domain, trying
    // to access ss.cssRules will throw a SecurityError. Hence, we must use
    // try/catch to detect this condition in Firefox.
    if(!ss.cssRules)
      return;
  } catch(e) {
    // Rethrow exception if it's not a SecurityError. Note that SecurityError
    // exception is specific to Firefox.
    if(e.name !== 'SecurityError')
      throw e;
    return;
  }

  // ss.cssRules is available, so proceed with desired operations.
  for(var i = 0; i < ss.cssRules.length; i++) {
    var rule = ss.cssRules[i];
    // Do something with rule
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah, but then how do you modify the style?

Comment: For anyone else getting this error in Firefox try running in safe mode. In my case it was one of my extensions causing this error.

Comment: In my case I started getting this only after I added a link to a google font. The stylesheet was outside my domain so it threw the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Firefox. Try this instead.

```
function getStyle(styleName, className) {

    for (var i=0;i<document.styleSheets.length;i++) {
        var s = document.styleSheets[i];

        var classes = s.rules || s.cssRules
        for(var x=0;x<classes.length;x++) {
            if(classes[x].selectorText==className) {
                return classes[x].style[styleName] ? classes[x].style[styleName] : classes[x].style.getPropertyValue(styleName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i need to *modify* the style