# Possible security issues with javascript function

Tags: javascript, webkit, browser

I have the following javascript function which works fine in Chrome, but fails in all other browsers.

```
function myFunction(a) {
    var sheets = document.styleSheets, o = {};

    for (var i in sheets) {
        var rules = sheets[i].rules || sheets[i].cssRules;

        for (var r in rules) {
            if (a.is(rules[r].selectorText)) {
                o = $.extend(o, css2json(rules[r].style), css2json(a.attr('style')));
            }
        }
    }
    return o;
}
```

In safari it appears to be the if statement that causing the problem giving the following error:

`Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration, input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button`

But in firefox it is the declaration of the rules variable where it breaks (giving a `The operation is insecure.` message).

Any ideas what the problem might be or how to fix it?

**EDIT**

If it matters, here's the css2json function:

```
function css2json(css) {

    var s = {};
    if (!css) return s;
    if (css instanceof CSSStyleDeclaration) {
        for (var i in css) {
            if ((css[i]).toLowerCase) {
                s[(css[i]).toLowerCase()] = (css[css[i]]);
            }
        }
    } else if (typeof css == "string") {
        css = css.split("; ");
        for (var i in css) {
            var l = css[i].split(": ");
            s[l[0].toLowerCase()] = (l[1]);
        }
    }

    return s;
}
```

**EDIT**

I've fixed the firefox bug by ignoring externally linked stylesheets.

Still not got it working in Safari though.

Comment: I presume the otherwise unreferenced css2json is https://github.com/kesla/css2json ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21642277/security-error-the-operation-is-insecure-in-firefox-document-stylesheets

Comment: Thanks @Andy - That put me on the right lines to fix the firefox issue, but I still have the problem with Safari. Any ideas on that one?

Comment: Not a one, I'm sorry. I don't currently have Safari in my workflow.

Comment: Nevermind! I just thought you might have seen the Error message before. I'll keep hunting for a solution.